# Variables in .env file is not updated. How to reset

Tags: javascript, vue.js, caching, environment-variables, quasar-framework

Im building an app with Quasar (vue) where I am using .env file to store my keys to the database. I was going to switch to another instance but after I changed the keys in the env file it still calls the old values of the variables. They seemd to be cached in some way.

Im using dotenv to call the env file.

I have tried of course to reset the history in browser as well as running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

How can I reset the env files?

Comment: did you re-start your dev-server, in some setup `.env` isn't refreshed until the whole dev server is restarted.

Comment: Perhaps your code is doing something wrong

Comment: `cache clean` doesn't make sense, that's the cache where npm packages are installed from. Possibly https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/commands-list#clean . Don't know if it's the case for Quasar but conventionally app-related cache is stored in node_modules/.cache/ and can be purged by deleting it

Comment: cache clean didnt work unfortunately. Yes I have restarted my dev-server. @JaromandaX yes that is possible. It could be something in quasar.config.js  in that case i cant figure out what

Answer (score 1):

Quasar handles env variables through `quasar.config.js` file, not separate `.env` files.  See the [documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#adding-to-process-env).

*quasar.config.js*

```js
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // ...

    build: {
      // passing down to UI code from quasar.config.js
      env: {
        API: ctx.dev
          ? 'https://dev.api.com'
          : 'https://prod.api.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As noted in the docs, if you do want to use `.env` files you'll have to add the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to your project and point `quasar.config.js` to use the env variables set with dotenv

```js
build: {
  env: require('dotenv').config().parsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a Quasar 2 / `Vite` / `pwa` app (I don't remember having it in `spa` mode before I switched).

Even if the hot reload works when I save my `.env` file (which works without dotenv by default for Vite env btw, as Quasar claims when starting `apps/quasar dev:  App • Using .env files: .env`), the values are not updated.

The workaround I found is to:

- Delete `./node_modules/.q-cache` folder
- Restart the dev server (`quasar dev`)

Also, if you don't find your newly added variables at all, don't forget to prefix them with `VITE_` or Vite will ignore them for security reasons.